# How end="" with the string print statement print in same line

Tags: python, printing

Everyone all of you. I am learning python right now.

In python, As you know that when we print anything using `print()` function it prints line by line like this:

```
print("Hello ")
print("World!")
```

When we do this then output would be:

```
Hello
World!
```

but if we want to be in same line we add `end=""` like this:

```
print("Hello ", end="")
print("World!")
```

Its output:

```
Hello World!
```

But I have curiosity that how does it exactly works. Why it comes in same line. The work of `end="____"` is to add some texts after sentences or words.

Please explain me why it comes in same line and what is the reason.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"The work of end="____" is to add some texts after sentences or words."` So, imagine that the default value for `end` is `'\n'`, then this makes perfect sense. If you "add some texts after sentences or words" and this "text" is `'\n'` then each "word" will be in a new line. What will happen if this "text" is an empty string?

Comment: Sorry, but I can not understand what you want to tell? Please explain in bit more detail

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? I'm not sure why you understand `end='\n'` but not `end=''`. It's essentialy the same as `''.join(...)` and `'\n'.join(...)`

Comment: I mean why when we add end="" then why it comes in same line. Sorry, but I am not understanding according to your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'end' tells the print function what to end your text with. Think of it as appending that string. 'end' defaults as '\n' meaning that a new line is appended to your string by default. So, if you change it to "", you are telling it not to alter or append to your string. Which means you simply print "Hello " instead of "Hello \n"

```
print ("Hello, Python")
```

The preceeding line will print to the console "Hello, Python\n" '\n' is a new line and it is the default behavior for the print function. It will by default always add '\n' to your string. If you supply 'end' to the function, it will print that instead of '\n'.

For example, the following two lines are identical in behavior:

```
print ("Hello, Python")
print ("Hello, Python",end="\n")
```

You could however provide your own 'end' to append a different string, if you so chose. For example:

```
print ("Hello, Python",end="!")
```

The preceeding line will print, "Hello, Python!"

For more information regarding new lines, check out the following:
https://wtmatter.com/python-new-line/

Comment: Sorry, but can you explain with example

Comment: Edited, hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is because In python when you print statement there is `end="\n"` as default in the python which allow it to print in another line but you will not see it. When you put `end=""` then it will replace with `\n` which print in different line and then it prints in same line. Hope it will help